# How to convert between a std::string and an Aws::String?

Tags: c++, aws-sdk

When attempting to convert a `std::string` to an `Aws::String` using the following code:

```
std::string s("Johnny is cool");
Aws::String aws_s(s);
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Aws::Allocator<char> >::basic_string(const string&)’
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/416. Thanks [Bu11etmagnet](https://github.com/Bu11etmagnet)!

---

If you have a `std::string` you want to pass to an Aws function, construct an `Aws::String` from it

```
std::string s{"whatever"};
Aws::String aws_s(s.c_str(), s.size());
Aws::SomeFunction(aws_s);
```

If you got an Aws::String from an Aws function, construct a std::string from it:

```
Aws::String const& aws_s = Aws::SomeFunction();
std::string s(aws_s.c_str(), aws_s.size());
```

Both of these perform a copy of the string content, unfortunately.

`Aws::String aws_s(std_string.c_str())` would measure the string length with strlen(), an information already contained in the std::string object.

Comment: The important point probably isnt't the inefficiency of re-calculating the length, but the possibility of embedded zeroes.

Comment: Will the string aws_s be null terminated though?

Comment: `aws_s` here is an object of type `Aws::String`, which is [defined](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/1.9.342/_a_w_s_string_8h_source.html#l00097) in the AWS C++ SDK to be a kind of `std::basic_string`. As [such](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), `aws_s.c_str()` should [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) a C-style null-terminated string.